# How do you pass Visual Studio Macros into the android gradle build script?

Tags: android, gradle, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to configure my android gradle project, and I want to use some of the project's configuration macros in the gradle script.

For example I'd like to add lib paths according to the configuration:

```
android.sources {
            main {

                jniLibs.source.srcDirs += "$(ProjectDir)/../../bin/Android/$(Configuration)" 

            }
    }
```

How do i access the Visaul Studio project macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around with passing the macros I want to the gradle command line as properties.

> **Project properties -> Configuration properties -> Gradle -> Additional**
> **Options:**
>
> -Pconfiguration=$(Configuration) -PprojectDir=$(ProjectDir)

Then I can assign the properties into local variables which i can use (need to assign the variables in the root scope:

```
def Configuration = configuration
def ProjectDir = projectDir

model {
    android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs.source.srcDirs += "$ProjectDir/../../bin/Android/$Configuration" 
        }
    }
}
```